# Свой фрэймворк вместо QOOXDOO. ООП-шим Яваскрипт.

Tags: framework, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Задался я целью на работе - избежать использования такого фрэймворка как QOOXDOO.
Он, конечно, классный и прикольный, но, к сожалению, и питон нужен для компиляции кода (да-да, чтобы собрать воедино код, нужен Питон), а еще он весит 100500 метров.

В общем, старался обойти без потерь для текущего проекта. Получилось вроде бы.

Из возможностей:

1. Возможность создания класса и его экземпляров.
2. Текущие типы классов, возможные для создания - динамический, синглтон.
3. Возможность "подмешивания" методов сторонних классов (МИКС).
4. чОткое наследование
5. Автоматическое создание Геттеров, сеттеров и листинга и контроля типов для публичный переменных.
6. Возможность создания статических методов вне статических классов.
7. оооооОоОооочень маленький.
   Текущие недоработки (будут исправлены в течении пары дней...когда высплюсь):
8. Нет возможности наследования синглтона. (функции написаны, но начинку не пихал. Там все просто)

Пример простейшего класса:

```
// Mixin class
smc.define("MTest", {
         // Static methds & properties
        static: {
                base: 0x100,
                unit: 0x200,
                resouce: 0x300
        }
});
// Mixin class
smc.define("MTest2", {
        // Static methds & properties
        static: {
                moto: 0x100,
                auto: 0x200,
                velo: 0x300
        }
});

smc.define("MyFirstClass", {
        /*
        * Конструктор. Вызывается при создании нового экземпляра класса.
        */
        construct: function (a,b) {
                if(a) this.setName(a);
                if(b) this.setMessage(b);
                this.helloWorld();
        },
        /*
        * Это примесь. Вы можете создать массив и указать SMC классы, 
        * чьи свойства необходимо подмешать в текущий объект класса.
        * Если такие классы есть - Вы сможете вызвать их методы, из текущего экземпляра,
        * либо обратится к их переменным
        */
        mixins: [
                smc.MTest,
                smc.MTest2
        ],
        /*  
        *  Это паблик- переменные класса.
        * value: Значение переменной
        * type: тип переменной (дефолт- любой)
        * event: Если при изменении значения переменной необходимо вызвать какую-либо функцию, 
        */
        properties: {
                name: { value: "Станислав", type: "string" },
                message: { value: "Привет", type: "string", apply: "this.helloWorld" }
        },
        /*
        * Список паблик функций, либо переменных
        * (как правило, сюда забрасываются переменные, которые не нуждаются в паблик доступе)
        */
        members: {
                helloWorld: function () {
                        alert( this.getMesage() + ", " + this.getName());
                }
        },
        static: {
                whatAreFuck: function () { console.log("Это простой статический метод у динамического объекта. Может вызываться без создания экземпляра класса") }
        }
});
```

Скачать его можно пройдя по этой ссылке :)
http://download.tracking.by/smc.js

Comment: А есть какое-нибудь сравнение с существующими микро-фреймворками?

Comment: Чем-то напоминает, но.... к сожалению, с кроссабраузерностью у него плёхо :( http://jsoop.codeplex.com/

Comment: а что тут сравнивать, это очень узко направленная библиотечка. как бы автор предложил в паблик, а кто захочет, сам допишет =)

Comment: Собственно, интересно мнение людей. Возможно, появятся какие-либо новые идеи у кого-нибудь для облегчения жизни :) Одна голова - это хорошо, ну а 100500 - хоть и не красиво смотреться на шее будут, но качественно :)

Comment: Фреймворк весом более 100 гиг? Круто!

Comment: Ну зачем слова принимать так близкой к сердцу :) Вес вродь около 90Мб  у qooxdoo)

Comment: А как вам [AtomJS — миниатюрный JavaScript фреймворк](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/110193/)?

Comment: Если я вижу надпись "Как и прежде — полный отказ от устаревших браузеров." - дальше не рассматриваю ) Разве что концепцию поведения, но не стану его использовать для реализации реальных задач )

Comment: реализация ООП, на мой взгляд, намного удобнее, да идея плагинов, хоть и не нова, но очень годная

Answer (score 2):

:) ЗАчетно, действительно, ничего тяжелого :) Но есть и нюансы.
1. Сразу бросилось в глаза с примером создания Юзера и Админа. Практически копипаст содержания одного объекта и второго. Думаю, никто не возразит, если я скажу, что это немного некрасиво :) Ну да ладно, тут дело вкуса, не имею права ничего говорить :)

Вот, хотел обратить внимание на фразу :
" сеттеры, геттеры и т.д и т.п. не стал т.к. не считаю целесообразным ( надо будет - можно написать "класс" с этим функционалом от которого, потом, расширять все )."

Не стоит расширять функционал за счет таковых лесапедов :) Тут фишка в чем. Почему я задался вопросом о реализации сеттеров и геттеров - очевидно.

1. Можно запросто контролировать типы переменных (а порой это очень важно)
2. Не придется писать к каждому геттеру и сеттеру функции всякие познавательные :) Как говориццо "Все уже сделано до нас:)" ... да и размер кода существенно уменьшается. :) У меня просто позиция такая - чем больше сделаешь сейчас - тем меньше потом делать всего :)

Comment: В JavaScript наследование и реализовываеться копипастом свойств одного объекта в другой (если быть точным - копипастом прототипа). К тому-же - копирование происходит единожды. Лично мне геттеры и сеттеры не нужны вообще, поэтому их реализацию я не писал.

А по поводу примера - я всего-лишь показал как этим пользоваться, написать крутой пример не задавался целью

Comment: К слову - на PHP этот пример был бы ненамного короче, так что не вижу проблемы в плане "много кода"
****
Кстати - у вас в коде используется `__proto__`, в IE это разве работает?

Comment: Нету возможности проверить )))) Я виндой не пользуюсь уже миллиарды лет ) НО! Виртуалку установлю, проверю, спасибо )))

Comment: А как у вас с `instanceof`?

И, быть может был невнимательным, но я так и не понял как создавать экземпляры класса.
****
К тому-же - в моем варианте классы "сами по себе", а не `smc.className`, не знаю как кому - а меня напрягает =)

Comment: Сорри, но у меня тоже все самом по себе :)
 
// Дальше будем работать с "Class" :)

var Class = new smc.ClassName("1", "params", {ololo: 123});

Comment: "Можно, но вот так: smc.MyFirstClass.whatAreFuck(); Спасибо за оценку )" а почему тут так?..

и вы пишите - new **smc.**className ;) и что с instanceof?

Comment: instanceof - какие типы с какими сравнивать Вы хотите ? :)) Приведите более подробный пример - более подробно смогу ответить :)

Относительно этого "smc.MyFirstClass.whatAreFuck(); " - это статический метод :) Его можно выполнить без наличия его экземпляра :)

Т.е. необязательно делать так:

var cls = new smc.MyFirstClass();
cls.whatAreFuck();

Можно просто: smc.MyFirstClass.whatAreFuck() :)))))

Answer (score 1):

И что, вот так можно вызвать функцию?

```
MyFirstClass::whatAreFuck();
```

А вообще круто.

Comment: Можно, но вот так: smc.MyFirstClass.whatAreFuck(); Спасибо за оценку )

Comment: object.mixins ? object.mixins : null == object.mixins || null

Comment: `MyFirstClass.whatAreFuck()` - вот так было бы круче.

Comment: гыгы, а как пишут jQuery("#ололо") ? :)Вот надпись jQuery никого не смущает :) А мои-то ... 3 буквы (и то, не матерные) не нравюцо :(

Comment: За jquery скрывается гораздо больший функционал чем у вас, соответственно там действительно есть необходимость в пространстве имен.

И кстати - `jQuery` пишут довольно редко, обычно просто `$` ;)

Comment: "За jquery скрывается гораздо больший функционал чем у вас" - Ну, не думаю, что можно сравнивать теплое с мягким )))

jQuery существенно упрощает работу с DOM контентом, мой же фрэймворк упрощает жизнь с логикой :)

Главное - моё детище не мешает работам любого другого фрэймворка параллельно :)

Comment: Переделывайте во общем.

Comment: А что переделывать то ?:)

Comment: Я вам написал достаточно косяков не вникая в то как вообще построена логика. Хотя бы это до ума доведите.

И у вас жесткий косяк, например:

    // допустим A это класс созданый с помощью
    // smc.define
    var a = new smc.A();
    a instanceof smc.A; // false

А это, мягко говоря, не нормально. Собственно то, что у вас это не работает уже говорит о многом, например о том, что вы не правильно работаете с прототипами.

PS: пример "чОткого" наследования так и не увидел.
PPS: с кроссбраузерностью определенно беда

Comment: По поводу jquery - речь шла о количестве функционала, ИМХО пространство имен в вашем случае не имеет смысла и лишь мусолит глаза. К тому-же я вообще не понимаю зачем хранить все классы?

Пользователь и так создает переменную и у вас есть return "класса". Т.е.:

     var someLolClass = smc.define(/* params here */);

someLolClass - и так "класс", так зачем-же хранить его в smc? Или за этим скрывается логика? Если да - так вы бы так и расписали, вообще по вашим ответам сложилось такое впечатление что вы, когда писали, вообще не понимали что делали. И сейчас толком не понимаете чего от вас хотят